# Cannot be cast From Fragment to Adapter (Cast fragment from onResponse)

Tags: android, android-fragments

I get an error when cast an object from `Fragment` via `onResponse` to **Adapter**, I want to create search in a `Fragment` using `SearchView.OnQueryTextListener`

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: dca.application.taaku.Main cannot be cast to dca.application.taaku.temp.paging.utils.PaginationAdapterCallback
                                                           at dca.application.taaku.hr.fragment.Approval.Sick.PaginationSearchAdapter.<init>(PaginationSearchAdapter.java:66)
                                                           at dca.application.taaku.hr.fragment.Approval.Sick.SickFragmentToAll$6.onResponse(SickFragmentToAll.java:317)
```

This code from `SickFragmentToAll`

```
     public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        RegisterAPI api = apiRetrofit.getClient().create(RegisterAPI.class);

        LeaveGroup = param.LeaveGroup_Sick;
        Status = param.Approved;
        Flag = param.Active;

        Call<Root> call = api.searchApproval(LeaveGroup,Status, Flag, newText);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Root>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Root> call, Response<Root> response) {
                int value = response.body().getValue();
                Log.d(TAG, "LOG onQueryTextChange : " + value);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                if (value == 1) {
                    Searchadapter = new PaginationSearchAdapter(getActivity());
                    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
                    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    if (CURRENT_PAGE <= TOTAL_PAGES)
                        adapter.addLoadingFooter();
                    else
                        isLastPage = true;
                }else if (value == 2){
                    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Root> call, Throwable t) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        });
        return true;
    }
```

And this is my **Adapter**

```
public PaginationSearchAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.mCallback = (PaginationAdapterCallback) context; // The problem here
    results = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

I've tried it with

```
adapter = new PaginationAdapter(getActivity(), this);
```

and

```
public PaginationAdapter(Context context, Fragment f) {
    this.context = context;
    this.mCallback = (PaginationAdapterCallback) f; // The problem here
    results = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

but it's not working

[UPDATE] 
I previously asked this on [Android Can not be cast From Fragment to Adapter (Cast fragment into class)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46291863/android-cannot-be-cast-from-fragment-to-adapter-cast-fragment-into-class) and I managed to find the answer ( which I marked with **checklist** ) but it was `onCreateView` and now the problem I need it on `onResponse`

[EDIT]

this is a Silly mistake, I forgot to import the `PaginationCallBack` class, it has been successfully and solved, thanks to the user who has helped me

Comment: is the `Fragment` you are passing to the `PaginationAdapter`'s constructor implementing `PaginationAdapterCallback`?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your class whose object is "mCallback" is implementing PaginationAdapterCallback.  Also make sure the fragment is correctly attached to the activity if re-using the fragment with more than one activity.